# Sum fixed number of cells of one column in data.table

Tags: r

I have a data table  :

```
> Data_train[order(Date)]
         Store DayOfWeek       Date Sales Customers Open Promo StateHoliday SchoolHoliday
      1:     1         2 2013-01-01     0         0    0     0            a             1
      2:     2         2 2013-01-01     0         0    0     0            a             1
      3:     3         2 2013-01-01     0         0    0     0            a             1
      4:     4         2 2013-01-01     0         0    0     0            a             1
      5:     5         2 2013-01-01     0         0    0     0            a             1
     ---                                                                                 
1017205:  1111         5 2015-07-31  5723       422    1     1            0             1
1017206:  1112         5 2015-07-31  9626       767    1     1            0             1
1017207:  1113         5 2015-07-31  7289       720    1     1            0             1
1017208:  1114         5 2015-07-31 27508      3745    1     1            0             1
1017209:  1115         5 2015-07-31  8680       538    1     1            0             1
```

I need to create a new variable that contains the sum of `sales` for each **42 days**

```
> Data_train[,Sales_6_weeks:=sum(Sales),by=42]
```

But it give me an error:

> Error in `[.data.table`(Data_train, , `:=`(Sales_6_weeks, sum(Sales)),
>   :    The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length (1). Each must
>   be same length as rows in x or number of rows returned by i (1017209).

What should I do please?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you dput sample of your data?

Comment: You are literally trying to group by the single value `c(42)` - which is trying to group `1017209` rows by a grouping vector of length `1`. The error is telling you exactly this. You need to make a counter somehow which divides your rows into blocks of 42 days. Take a look at `cut` - `cut(Sys.Date()+0:9, breaks="2 days")` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your stated question, you can do

```
Data_train[, Sales_6_weeks := sum(Sales), by = as.numeric(Date - min(Date)) %/% 42]
```

But it looks like you probably want to do this instead

```
Data_train[, Sales_6_weeks := sum(Sales), by = lubridate::week(Date) %/% 6]
```

Comment: thank you but it give me an error  _Error in Date - min(Date) : non-numeric argument to binary operator_

Comment: I made an edit to add `as.numeric`. When you tried it did you use the updated version of my answer?